# Malformed root json

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, build, expo

After npx expo build --local the build is failed. I got only this:

> - What went wrong:
>   [RUN_GRADLEW] Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
>   [RUN_GRADLEW] > Malformed root json

Here is my package.json:

`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "publish": "expo start",
    "lint": "eslint App.tsx",
    "audit": "audit-ci",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "echo $GOOGLE_SERVICES_BASE64 | base64 --decode > ./google-services.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex": "^7.16.7",
    "@expo/config": "~8.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
    "@types/react-native-tab-view": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@use-expo/font": "^2.0.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.6",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.4",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^5.0.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1022.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "fix": "^0.0.6",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.13",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-email-link": "^1.14.1",
    "react-native-gallery-swiper": "^1.26.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.6",
    "react-native-mime-types": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-purchases": "5.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.0",
    "audit-ci": "^6.6.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.5.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "ghooks": "^2.0.4",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "ownname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://ownurl"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://ownurl
  },
  "homepage": "https://ownurl"
}
```

`

Here is my app.json

`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "ownproperty",
    "slug": "ownproperty",
    "scheme": "ownproperty",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.4.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/logo_white.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "ownproperty",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#808080"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./src/assets/images/logo.png"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "enabled": false,
      "url": "ownproperty"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "sentry-expo",
      "expo-tracking-transparency",
      "react-native-email-link",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33
          }
        }
      ],
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "dewise",
            "project": "ownproperty",
            "authToken": "ownproperty"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "ownproperty,
      "buildNumber": "1.4.0",
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIRequiresFullScreen": true,
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "We use Tracking for a third party services (Firebase), We create a better user experience from your data and we can detect the errors.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "App needs to access your camera roll so that you can upload images. Images are necessary to create your own profile. Your images will not be shared with any 3rd party services.",
        "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": [
          "mailto",
          "message",
          "readdle-spark",
          "airmail",
          "ms-outlook",
          "googlegmail",
          "inbox-gmail",
          "ymail",
          "superhuman",
          "yandexmail",
          "fastmail",
          "protonmail"
        ]
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "entitlements": {
        "com.apple.developer.applesignin": [
          "Default"
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "ownproperty",
      "googleServicesFile": "google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 58,
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "NOTIFICATIONS"
      ]
    },
    "description": "",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "ownproperty"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

`

I've tried npx expo-doctor and fix the dependencies. I downgraded expo to 48.